# jmeter regex to ignore whitespace and new line

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have a sampler that returns the following in the Response data:

> ```
> for API key "fmgflanjs", use API key secret:
>
>   afgthgdsf
>
> Note that it's norm
> ```

In jmeter, I am now trying to extract out the variables key (in the quotation marks but not including quotation marks) and secret (on line 2) using regex like this on this response data. But have not been able to get it to work so far. Any help is much appreciated.

For the key, I tried this regex: key(?s) "(.*?)"

For the secret, I tried this regex: secret:(?s)(.*?)(?s) Note

Comment: The first one - `"([^"]*)"`, and the second one `(\S+)\s*[\r\n]+Note`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For the key:**

```
Regular Expression: "([^"]*)"
Template: $1$
Match No: 1
```

Regex means: capture a group (in parentheses), that is between 2 double quotes. The group can contain any character except for double quotes

**For the secret:**

```
Regular Expression: secret:[\s]*(.*)[\s]*Note
Template: $1$
Match No: 1
```

Regex means: capture a group (in parentheses), that is between 2 optional sets of whitespace, preceded by 'secret:' and followed by 'Note'

Or you can get them **both at once**:

```
Reference name: key
Regular Expression: for API key "(.*)", use API key secret:[\s]*(.*)[\s]*Note that it's norm
Template: $1$
```

Since regex selects multiple groups, JMeter will create multiple variables with names that follow the template `refname_gN`, so in our case:

```
key_g1
key_g2
```